# Bluestacks - Error: Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation

Tags: android, windows, bluestacks

BlueStacks App Plaer.
Error: Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.

[image]

I install it use it everthink is OK but after computer reboot this happens.

I set the full right acces to the c://ProgramData, but nothing happens. 
I am on fresh installation on WIndows 7 and use 2.2.21.6212 version.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check .NET Framework is installed on the system.
if not install the latest version
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4.5 has already been installed on this computer.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is in some of the dll of the system I think. And is because of the windows size. SO if you are fast and resize the Bluestacks to full screen the error dissapears. It is not clear as a descision but works.